# handleOpenChange triggering before onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using shadcn/ui's [Dialog](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/dialog) component and [Form](https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/form) component, which uses [react-form-hook](https://react-hook-form.com/).

```
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
  resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
  defaultValues: {
    name: 'Figma',
    category: 'Software',
    version: '1.0',
    location: 'Taipei',
    status: 'Available',
  },
});

const onSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
  const newItems = {
    ...values,
  };

  setItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, newItems]);
};

const handleOpenChange = (open) => {
  setIsOpen(open);

  if (!open) {
    form.reset()
  }
};

return (
  <Dialog open={isOpen} onOpenChange={handleOpenChange}>
    <DialogContent>
      <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <input type="text" {...form.register("exampleFieldName")} />
          <DialogClose asChild>
            <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
          </DialogClose>
          <DialogClose asChild>
            <Button type="button" variant="secondary">
              Close
            </Button>
          </DialogClose>
        </form>
      </Form>
    </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>
)
```

The issue here is that `handleOpenChange` always triggers before `onSubmit` (whether I click the Submit or Close button. This means the form will reset before submitting.

Is this how the Dialog `onOpenChange` and the form `onSubmit` are supposed to behave together? If so, how to solve this issue?

Comment: try to `form.reset()` on `onSubmit` function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you remove the
`<DialogClose>`
component? Is there a reason to use it?

Comment: Please use the comments for additional follow up questions rather than the answer section.

Comment: @NickParsons sorry, I editted the answer

Comment: Is this an answer though? It still seems more like a question to me. I assume OP wants the DialogClose component so that the dialog closes when they click one of the buttons (which perhaps there are other ways to achieve, which would form part of your answer).

Comment: I think there is another way to archive it, you put the code to close the dialog in the ````onSubmit```` function